# FutureProvider is not caching the response

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm Using futureProvider to get some response from server but when I put arguments in the futureProvider, it refuses to cache the data. when I remove those arguments then it caches perfectly.

```
final getCoursesByCategoriesProvider =
    FutureProvider.family<List<Course>, ArgsModel>((ref, vendocode) async {
  return ref.watch(courseControllerProvider).getCoursesByCategories(
      category: vendocode.firstParams, context: vendocode.secondParams);
});
```

I want to cache those data too.
Is this even possible?

Comment: Do you mean the provider doesn't cache data when the arguments is the same?

Comment: arguments is same but when I get back to that page from another page it doesn't caching the data but if I remove those arguments then it perfectly caches the data.

Comment: Can you give example on how you pass the argument to the provider?

Comment: it's a bit lengthy code but I can tell you that the category param is passed from a another notifier provider which stores the selected Category and then i uses ref.watch(selectedCategory); to get the latest data and pass it to the argument and context param is passed from the Buildcontext of the page.
Hope I explained correctly.

Comment: `List<Course>` is not a valid family key.  It needs to be something that has a useful equality operation.

Answer (score 2):

The reason provider doesn't cache the data is probably because every `ArgsModel` passed to the provider is a different instance, even if the parameters inside have the same values. To fix this, you need to override `operator ==` and `hashCode` in the `ArgsModel` class. Follow the example [here](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#implementing-map-keys).

Alternatively, you can use Riverpod's latest syntax which uses [code generation](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/about_code_generation). This allows you to define more than one parameter to the provider, and `ArgsModel` is no longer needed.

Here's an example code (note that I'm assuming the type of `firstParams` and `secondParams`):

```dart
@riverpod
Future<List<Course>> coursesByCategories(
  CoursesByCategoriesRef ref, {
  required String firstParams,
  required String secondParams,
}) async {
  return ref.watch(courseControllerProvider).getCoursesByCategories(
    category: firstParams,
    context: secondParams,
  );
}
```

Comment: i did all of that also did generator also, still no luck

`@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
Future<List<Course>> getCoursesByCategories(GetCoursesByCategoriesRef ref, {required String category, required BuildContext context}) {
 return ref.watch(courseControllerProvider).getCoursesByCategories(
      category: category, context: context);
}`

Comment: You shouldn't pass BuildContext to providers https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod_lint#avoid_build_context_in_providers-riverpod_generator-only